# Was this a correct approach? Is there a simpler one?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I came across this problem:
![enter image description here][1]

Now, I have since learned that an "inverted" cone is one with the pointy part of the bottom.  So, an ice cream cone is an inverted cone.

I did the problem thinking an inverted cone was a wizard's hat.  So, water is draining from the bottom of the wizard’s hat.  This turns out to be a slightly more complex and fun problem.

But, there are 2 shapes that are changing.  The emoty air cone up top and the 3D trapezoidal water on the bottom.  But, I have no idea what the volume of the lower water section is, so I focused on the volume of the air cone.  Either should work, since we’re after dh/dt.   Right?   I am curious if I did the wrong problem correctly, by using rates of change of the "air cone" vs. the 3D-trapezoidal shape of the actual water on the bottom. ....Anyone care to validate my approach?  Thanks!

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: It's legible, no?

Comment: Thanks.  Funny that the volume of the entire was a moot point.   Ahh, good catch.  dh/dt can be referring to two different heights (air cone height vs. water height)   air cone's dh/dt is (+) and water's dh/dt is (-).

Comment: Thanks to G-man.   Can you paste your response as an answer, and I will approve it?